# how to make a row of triangles using loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, html5-canvas

How do I make a row of triangles?

Here's the code I have so far.

I'm new I don't know what to do here.

```js
function showDrawing() {
  let coolCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(126, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 400);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 400);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="700" style="border:3px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<button onclick="showDrawing()">Drawing</button>
```

Comment: Make sure you use the same variable name for your canvas throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the iteration (i) and multiply it by the spacing you want and add it to the x value.

```js
function showDrawing() {
    let coolCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = coolCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(126+(i*170), 300); 
        ctx.lineTo(200+(i*170), 400); 
        ctx.lineTo(50+(i*170), 400);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="700" style="border:3px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<button onclick="showDrawing()">Drawing</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a variable to add to the X positions and increment as you want :

```js
function showDrawing() {
    let coolCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let delta = 0;
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(126 + delta, 300); 
        ctx.lineTo(200 + delta, 400); 
        ctx.lineTo(50 + delta, 400);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        
        delta += 174;
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="700" style="border:3px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<button onclick="showDrawing()">Drawing</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate function to handle drawing the triangles, then pass in the `xStart` as the base x-coordinate value for any triangle to be drawn. Then in the `showDrawing` function, run a loop and multiply the `i` variable to some spacing value. In your code, your triangle is 150 pixels wide and starts at x-value of 50, so I multiplied the `i` value by `200` for consistency in my solution code.

Additionally, I **highly advise** using the variable name you set (`coolCanvas`) as the reference to the canvas or set this variable to be named `canvas` instead. If you only ever set the canvas once and reference it once, you can probably skip setting the reference altogether:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
```

```js
function drawTriangle(ctx, xStart) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xStart + 126, 300);
  ctx.lineTo(xStart + 200, 400);
  ctx.lineTo(xStart + 50, 400);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.stroke();
}

function showDrawing() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    drawTriangle(ctx, i * 200);
  }
}
document.getElementById("draw").addEventListener("click", showDrawing);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div><button id="draw">Drawing</button></div>
<div><canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="700"></canvas></div>
```